# Weekly Tasks in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Im currently trying to make a week calendar, where the person has a particular task every week (depending on week number). I think i'm on the right track, but Conditional Formating is a bit icky to get around.

- Based of the week number on row 1, Color the tabs down (as done in the screen shot)
- Based of the letters below the current week, Colorize the Person (for example, This week Person 2 will be green, Person 4 will be cyan)

This is how far i've gotten.

[Picture of current progress on the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tAZc.png)

I tried to do normal formulas, but I assume here I would need to use Conditional Formatting.
I tried to have multiple formulas, but either I am not doing them in correct order.

=WEEKNUM(TODAY()) is what I use to find the week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try this within `Conditional format rules`:*

***Apply to range***: `A2:A5`

***Custom formula is***: `=offset(A2;;weeknum(today()))="B"`

- *this is for code **`B`** (green)*

Comment: It's getting there, but I don't want the blocks with the value colored, but rather the A2:A5 column instead, for example if AM3 and AM5 colored, color Person 2 Green and Person 4 Cyan.

Comment: `Player 2` is supposed to be colored green since `AM3` has `B` OR its because `AM3` is manually colored yellow as shown in the screenshot. same query goes for Player 4; is it bcoz of AM5="K" OR  highlighted yellow?!

Comment: Yes the first one. The yellow one is conditional format aswell.

Comment: Do try out the updated solution